# xml values not right

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm trying to enumerate all hosts in an XML document, create a db entry for each host, then add each host's users (also from the XML document) to the db that are tied to that foreign key. The message box in the code below displays each user more times than there are `<user>` elements. I expected to see "a", "b" and "c" just twice each, but the code doesn't seem to stop displaying them.

```
    private void simple_test()
    {
        var xml =
"<root>
  <main>
    <host>
      <sub>
        <user>
          <name>
            a
          </name>
        </user>
        <user>
          <name>
            b
          </name>
        </user>
        <user>
          <name>
            c
          </name>
        </user>
      </sub>
    </host>
    <host>
      <sub>
        <user>
          <name>
            a
          </name>
        </user>
        <user>
          <name>
            b
          </name>
        </user>
        <user>
          <name>
            c
          </name>
        </user>
      </sub>
    </host>
  </main>
</root>";

        var xml_reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml));

        var xpath_doc = new XPathDocument(xml_reader);
        var xpath_nav = xpath_doc.CreateNavigator();
        XPathExpression expr;
        expr = xpath_nav.Compile("//host/*");

        var xpni = xpath_nav.Select(expr);

        while(xpni.MoveNext())
        {
            if (xpni.Current == null) continue;
            var nav = xpni.Current.Clone();

            expr = nav.Compile("//user/*");
            var xpni2 = nav.Select(expr);

            while (xpni2.MoveNext())
            {
                if (xpni2.Current == null) continue;
                var nav2 = xpni2.Current.Clone();

                nav2.SelectSingleNode("//name");

                MessageBox.Show(nav2.Value);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to enumerate all hosts, create a db entry for each host, then add users to the db that are tied to that foreign key.

Comment: Please add an `@` before the string. A string spanning multiple lines needs to be a verbatim literal.

Comment: @Bluebaron: please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. Always state the [overall goal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) so your questions don't suffer from the XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the others have demonstrated, there are more elegant ways to achieve what you need; however, if you’re looking for bugs in your code, here are two.

First:

```
var nav2 = xpni.Current.Clone();
```

should presumably be

```
var nav2 = xpni2.Current.Clone();
```

Second:

```
expr = nav.Compile("//user/*");
```

This would match *any* `user` elements in your document, and not just descendants of the current `sub`. Per the [XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) on MSDN:

- `//author` matches all `<author>` elements in the document.
- `.//title` matches all `<title>` elements one or more levels deep in the current context.

Thus, if you want to match all `user` elements that are descendants of the current `sub` *at any level*, you may use:

```
expr = nav.Compile(".//user/*");
```

In your case, since all `user` elements are direct children, it would be more efficient to use the following snippet:

```
expr = nav.Compile("./user/*");
```

which is equivalent to:

```
expr = nav.Compile("user/*");
```

This avoids unnecessarily traversing the hierarchy looking for deeper-nested elements which don’t exist.

**Edit**: Removed some incorrect remarks pointed out in the comments.

Comment: This was just a small tester app function that I made.  The first one isn't my issue.  The actual issue is the xpath query.  It's weird, though, if I inspect the outerxml of the xpni, it doesn't have the values it's giving back.  Really weird how a bad xpath can do that.

Comment: What makes you think it deviates from the spec? That's exactly the correct behavior.

Comment: You’re right; I misread the spec. I’ll fix my post.

Comment: The key is that anywhere you see `//` you can replace it with `/descendant-or-self::node()/` and anywhere you see `.` you can replace it with `self::node()`. So, `//user` becomes `/descendant-or-self::node()/user` (which starts at the root), but `.//user` becomes `self::node()/descendant-or-self::node()/user` (which does not). As that MSDN link mentions, this is really the only time you need `.` in a location step.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it really well.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
private void simple_test()
    {
        var xml =
            "<root><main><host><sub><user><name>a</name></user><user><name>b</name></user><user><name>c</name></user></sub></host><host><sub><user><name>a</name></user><user><name>b</name></user><user><name>c</name></user></sub></host></main></root>";

        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

       foreach(var name in doc.descendants("name")){

         MessageBox.Show(name.Value);

       }     
    }
```

I didn't test but it should work.

Good Luck!

Comment: The whole point is to use xpath and to insert the values into a db.  The host node needs to be added to the db and then the id for that needs to be passed to all users so I can set the foreign key.

Comment: OK, you didn't specify that, so I didn't know ;).  In any case, I haven't used much xpath so I can leave that up to other contributors, but I would contend that you can probably still do whatever you need going down the `XDocument`, uh, path.

Comment: Won't compile but I will make the working Correction that you need BlueBaron

Comment: @DJKRAZE--It will now.  I added the type initializer ahead of 'name' in the foreach.  Intellisense would have told the OP that.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var xml =
"<root>
   <main>
     <host>
       <sub>
         <user>
           <name>a</name>
         </user>
         <user>
           <name>b</name>
         </user>
         <user>
           <name>c</name>
         </user>
       </sub>
     </host>
     <host>
        <sub>
          <user>
            <name>a</name>
          </user>
          <user>
            <name>b</name>
          </user>
          <user>
            <name>c</name>
          </user>
        </sub>
     </host>
   </main>
 </root>";

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    foreach(string name in doc.Descendants("name"))
    {
       MessageBox.Show(name);
    }
```

outputs:
a
b
c
a
b
c

Comment: I'll just copy the comments I made on the two entries above so you can read them a little better.

Comment: The whole point is to use xpath and to insert the values into a db. The host node needs to be added to the db and then the id for that needs to be passed to all users so I can set the foreign key.

Comment: I'm trying to enumerate all hosts, create a db entry for each host, then add users to the db that are tied to that foreign key.

Comment: Ok so where are the host names in the xml file you may want to reconstruct your question and example of the XML File you want out put of a b c the Answer Patrick gave won't work let alone compile

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/host[$k]/sub/user/name
```

where `$k` can take a value from 1 to `count(/*/*/host)`.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/host">
   <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
   <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/host[$vPos]/sub/user/name"/>

   ============


  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided one, slightly modified so that the names under different slots are different):

```
<root>
    <main>
        <host>
            <sub>
                <user>
                    <name>a</name>
                </user>
                <user>
                    <name>b</name>
                </user>
                <user>
                    <name>c</name>
                </user>
            </sub>
        </host>
        <host>
            <sub>
                <user>
                    <name>a2</name>
                </user>
                <user>
                    <name>b2</name>
                </user>
                <user>
                    <name>c2</name>
                </user>
            </sub>
        </host>
    </main>
</root>
```

**the wanted elements are selected and copied to the output**. In the output between two selection results there is a string delimiter ("========") to make the individual selection results easily identifiable:

```
<name>a</name>
<name>b</name>
<name>c</name>

   ============


<name>a2</name>
<name>b2</name>
<name>c2</name>

   ============
```